# Combine two where clause queries , one with DATE FORMAT, in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have these two `where` clauses to select data from table. I want to combine these two into one. When I added `AND`, it doesn't give output. It works fine if I used it separately.... But I want two `where` condition to work at same time

```
$this->db->where("(DATE_FORMAT(from_date,'%m') = '$m' AND DATE_FORMAT(from_date,'%Y') = '$y')OR (DATE_FORMAT(to_date,'%m') = '$m' AND DATE_FORMAT(to_date,'%Y') = '$y' )");
$this->db->where("resource","$e");

$this->db->order_by("status","desc");
```

Comment: use $this->db->and_where ("resource","$e");

Comment: where?     code  $query = $this->db->get();
        $users = $query->result(); code   hrere?

Comment: please specify full code.i used this single where condition and worked fine in $this->db->where("(DATE_FORMAT(from_date,'%m') = '$m' AND DATE_FORMAT(from_date,'%Y') = '$y') OR (DATE_FORMAT(to_date,'%m') = '$m' AND DATE_FORMAT(to_date,'%Y') = 'y' ) and resources = '$e'");

Comment: it doesn't work for me.. so i have a table,wants to select leaves with specific month and year for specific employees,so i input both month and year , and employee name..that is passed to model via controller.so this is my 'sql' to list down rows satisfying both conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$where = "((DATE_FORMAT(from_date,'%m') = '$m' AND DATE_FORMAT(from_date,'%Y') = '$y') OR (DATE_FORMAT(to_date,'%m') = '$m' AND DATE_FORMAT(to_date,'%Y') = '$y')) AND 'resource' = '$e'";
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->order_by("status","desc");
```